# How do I check if the strings inside an array are part of another string?

Tags: sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a dynamic array of strings. I would like to check if some of the elements are equal to or sometimes also part of an input string.

I came up with this example:

```sql
SELECT array_contains(array("ghi", "def", "%abc"), "foobabc")
```

This, however, does not work and returns `false`.

Is there any other way to do this besides building a large clause with `LIKE` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `array_contains` function in your example checks if the input string `"foobabc"` is an exact match for any of the elements in the array `["ghi", "def", "%abc"]`. Since there is no exact match, the function returns `false`. In order to check if array element has partial or exact match with the string `"fooabc"`, you can follow the below approach.

**Code:**

```
SELECT  array("ghi", "def", "abc") as array_col,transform(array("ghi", "def", "abc"), value ->  contains("fooabc",value)) as contains_col, array_max(transform(array("ghi", "def", "abc"), value ->  contains("fooabc",value))) as array_contains_col
```

The `transform` function creates a new array that contains a boolean value for each element in the original array. The `contains` function within transform is used to check if the input string `"fooabc"` contains exactly or partially each element in the array. The resulting array `contains_col` will contain `[false, false, true]`, since `"abc"` is the only element in the array that is a substring of `"fooabc"`. The  `array_max`  function is then used to find the maximum value in the  `contains_col`  array, which is  `true`. The result of the  `array_max`  function is a scalar value, which is assigned to the alias  `array_contains_col`.

[image]

This is the approach to check if an input string contains any of the elements in the array.